# Server mismatch error in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have to backup a database using remote desktop connection in PGAdmin.I have installed three versions in my client machine 9.1,9.2,9.3.In server i am using 9.3.While trying to backup its showing server version mismatch error.Eventhough i have installed 9.3 version,dont know why its not working.

```
D:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.1\bin\pg_dump.exe --host 192.99.197.25 --port 5432 --username "postgres" --no-password  --format custom --blobs --verbose --file "D:\V\QuartzBee dbbackup\QuartzBee_19_3_15.backup" "QuartzBee"
pg_dump: server version: 9.3.6; pg_dump version: 9.1.3
pg_dump: aborting because of server version mismatch
pg_dump: *** aborted because of error

Process returned exit code 1.
```

how can i change the pg_dump from 9.1 and set 9.3 as default.

Comment: You're using `D:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.1\bin\pg_dump.exe`. If you have 9.3 installed, wouldn't `D:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\bin\pg_dump.exe` work then?

Comment: How to invoke that .Could you help me@Petter

Comment: I am using ,by right click on the database and then  i have tried to backup

Comment: I think this question belongs to http://dba.stackexchange.com/ not to Stackoverflow. But, the answer to the question is obvious: you're using the wrong version of pg_dump.

Answer (score 15):

In pgAdmin, navigate to File -> Options, and under Browser -> Binary paths, change `PG bin path` to `D:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.1\bin`. That should make it use the 9.3 executables.

Comment: @Petter: I am working on Ubuntu 14.04. I don't have any pg_dump executable in my etc/PostgreSQL/9.4/main. What should i do?

Comment: this is the simplest and only working solution on entire web :)

Answer (score 4):

In pgAdmin 4, this navigation route is now:

File -> Preferences -> Paths -> Binary Paths

Comment: There is no option to "Ignore server version mismatch" in pgAdmin 4 under this navigation route. Was it moved or removed?

Comment: @FireEmerald you need to upgrade postgresql db version and update in the binary path of pgadmin as mentioned in the post, it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the binaries of pg_dump.
OR
You can simply ignore server/utility version mismatches. 
Please navigate to File > Options. Then, Browser > Binary Paths.
Click on the checkbox with label **ignore server/utility version mismatches**
Refresh you database tree. It will work. 
Thanks

[image]

Comment: how to open this menu ?

Comment: @DimitrisKougioumtzis, From top menu, Please navigate to File > Options. Then, Browser > Binary Paths.

Comment: I want to take a backup and restore production DB so by enabling ignore server/utility version mismatches option will it have any adverse effect or issue on new restore Prod DB?

Comment: Furthermore, I got the error on enabling  ignore server/utility version mismatches option : C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin III\1.22\pg_dump.exe: illegal option -- ignore-version

Comment: Note I my Prod db is RDS Postgres

Comment: @AshishKarpe, to avoid any issue on Production Server, I mostly restore a DB by a snapshot. To prevent the version incompatibility issue. I'll recommend downloading a the posgtres version of your production server and use it to take the dump.
https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/pgadmin/pgadmin3/
Please download postgres version that you have on production server and place the the extract folder in in C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin III\YOUR_SERVER_VERSION
Then, in the Pg bin path use that version, C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin III\YOUR_SERVER_VERSION
Hopefully, it will work out! :)

Answer (score 2):

For Windows, after I upgraded postgres,I still need update \ Preference \ Paths \ Binary paths

**FROM:** $DIR/../runtime  (This was the default)

**TO:** C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\bin

[image]

I do not enjoy this experience.